# looking for a comparable service like one.com, but need more domain parkings? any ideas?

Tags: web-hosting, email, mobile, parking, domains

I have a simple and small website, webshop, email and mobile version.

one.com would be OK for this, but I want to store some more domains which one.com won't allow.

Thanks a lot people!

rikolino

Answer (score 0):

If you require domain parking below will suit you fine... If your looking for a web host with parking then GoDaddy...

- [Sedo](http://sedo.co.uk)
- [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com)
- [123 Reg](http://www.123-reg.co.uk)
- [Domain Parking](http://www.domainparking.com/)
- [And lots more on Google.....](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=domain%20parking)